# Unnecesarry canvases created by react-webcam

Tags: reactjs, canvas, web-applications, lag, webcam-capture

I am using **react-webcam** in my React Typescript application, and there is a scenario when user have to take around 100 photos in one session. So with this function I get the screenshot and the add the image to states and later proceed the logic and after sending the request application again redirects to camera page to take a picture:

```
  const capture = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isMounted && webcamRef.current !== null) {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current?.getScreenshot();
      if (imageSrc) {
         store.dispatch(commitSourceImage(imageSrc));
      }
    }
  }, [isMounted, webcamRef]);
```

The problem is that when I inspect the application through **Safari browser(in Graphics section)**
I can see [Multiple Canvases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFcFE.jpg), so each time when I reopen camera page and take a picture **new canvas** is created. After some tries the app is r**eaching the maximum size of Canvas 384 MB** and it blocks taking picture. Also after **10-15 tries** as the canvas limit is reaching top, the application and mainly the camera is **starting to lag**.  Want to mention that **canvases are not inside html elements** so it **is not a part of Virtual Dom**

**Refreshing page is deleting all canvases and fixing all lagging problem!**

Do you have any solution how to **avoid creating multiple canvases** or even **deleting old canvases** and keeping only one?

```
 <Webcam
          style={{
                borderRadius: '12px',
                margin: '10px 0',
                border: '2px solid blue',
                objectFit: 'cover',
              }}
              width={'100%'}
              ref={webcamRef}
              forceScreenshotSourceSize={true}
              screenshotFormat='image/jpeg'
              videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
              hidden={sourceImage != null}
            />
```

I am expecting to have single canvas for the session, so not creating a new canvas each time.